# at what temperature does it become expeditious to use a lithium battery's charge to heat itself?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

battery capacity diminishes the colder the battery gets. Is there a point where it's worth using the battery's energy to warm it up, increasing capacity? If so, where's the break-even point? If not, how wasteful is it to do so?

Comment: When photographing near the Arctic, I would permanently have one battery in my camera and one or two in my armpits.  Every five or so minutes, camera battery dies and gets swapped with re-warmed battery from armpit.  I can't give you an exact temperature for when self-heated batteries would be practical, but I can say with certainty that below -20, they're a necessity!

Comment: when you were a child, sometimes the doctor placed the thermometer in your armpit to keep you from gagging. Do you remember the temperatures taken then? Do you think it's changed much? What is the thermal dissipation capacity of the average armpit, and how significantly was this impeded by the body's tendency to shunt blood flow to the core in adverse conditions? Do you have any technical schematics on your body, where did you purchase it, and do you consider it a worthwhile investment, or do you wish you had another with better armpit performance? @MarkKCowan

Comment: I wish it was less leaky the rest of the time!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the answer, depending on the battery, by reading the datasheets. There cannot be an universal answer.

http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/l91.pdf

Check the graph "Temperature effect on capacity". Pick your load current, calculate

$$
maximum\_additional\_load = I_{load} \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{available\_capacity@ambient\_temperature}{available\_capacity@desired\_temperature} \right)
$$
as the current you can use to heat the battery from ambient temperature to the desired temperature. The value depends on both of them.

If you can reach the desired temperature with less than that amount of current, it is worth it.

You can see by the slope of the curves that heating the battery to -30°C is very useful (steep slope), then heating the battery to 0°C is much less useful (much flatter slope) and over 0°C makes no sense.

For that battery.

Comment: 'if you can reach with less than...' yes! I agree. Do you know off the top of your head if (have you seen enough data sheets to say) the performance is roughly similar between your linked battery, and others?)